# Can the same x509 certificate have two different PEM encoding?

Tags: x509certificate, x509

It was my belief that the PEM encoding were unique.

But I have seen that the same certificate can have two different pem versions. Or at least, I have two PEM certificates that contain the same information (serial number, CA issuer etc...) so they should be the same.

Can the same certificate have two different PEM encoding?

Comment: Try running them both through `openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -text` which will dump the contents of the certificates. (You'll have openssl as part of your git installation if nowhere else.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no two different encoding versions for same set of certificate data.

Presentation in PEM may be slightly different. I mean, PEM may include or missing PEM header and footer, Base64-encoded payload may or may not have line breaks after 64 characters, but it doesn't affect the Base64-encoded value, because line breaks are not part of encoding and ignored by Base64 encoder/decoder. The raw value unchanged for single certificate.

Update:

Exact PEM format is defined in [RFC 1421](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421), but it is not always followed and I see different presentations which can be called PEM as well (even though they don't strictly follow RFC). For example, I saw such as:

```
-----BEGIN XYX-----
<Base64 string split in 64 chars per line>
<Base64 string split in 64 chars per line>
<Base64 string split in 64 chars per line>
-----END XYZ-----
```

or

```
-----BEGIN XYX-----
<Long Base64 string split in single line (without line breaks>
-----END XYZ-----
```

or even this:

```
-----BEGIN XYX-----<Long Base64 string split in single line (without line breaks>-----END XYZ-----
```

or variations of these formats. Only first example is legit PEM format, while the rest are not-compliant, but can be called PEM, because they have PEM header and footer, and Base64-encoded payload.

Comment: The pre- and post-encapsulation boundaries are *not* optional in PEM. Differences in whitespace can exist, but without boundaries, it's no longer PEM.

Comment: Linebreaks are not required for _base64_ in general, and in some other standards like XML and JSON, leading some (many?) parsers to be lax, but linebreaks every 64 absolutely are required in PEM as defined by RFC1421 4.3.2.4 and reaffirmed by RFC7468 2.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the nonstandard but often accepted (mis)encodings described by [Crypt32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58833610/2868801):

As stated in [RFC7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#section-5) several different 'types' have been used for X.509 certificates, including plain `CERTIFICATE` or `X509 CERTIFICATE` or `X.509 CERTIFICATE`. These contain the same data, and it's debatable whether this is really a different encoding.

OpenSSL, and some things compatible with it, have a related but distinct PEM type `TRUSTED CERTIFICATE` where the data actually consists of the X.509 certificate (in DER) plus an added DER blob containing trust information proprietary to OpenSSL. This is different, but only a little.

A certificate, or several,  can be packaged in a PKCS7 or CMS 'container', often using the p7b or p7c extension if it's in a file or URL. A PKCS7/CMS *containing* a cert is a different thing from the cert itself, though it can sometimes be used interchangeably (Microsoft CertMgr, I'm looking at you), and the PEM encoding of a PKCS7/CMS containing a cert is different from that of the cert itself.

Comment: I upvoted because it is a really good answer, but I think the other is the most correct answer to my question. sorry :)

Comment: No problem. I meant this to add alternatives that might be useful to you or someone else who comes along, not to reject the other; clarified.